# Whats wrong with my query with CASE statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, case

I'm trying to solve #13 on http://www.sqlzoo.net/wiki/The_JOIN_operation

"List every match with the goals scored by each team as shown. This will use "CASE WHEN" which has not been explained in any previous exercises."

**Here's my query:**

```
SELECT game.mdate, game.team1, 
SUM(CASE WHEN goal.teamid = game.team1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS score1,
game.team2,
SUM(CASE WHEN goal.teamid = game.team2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS score2

FROM game INNER JOIN goal ON matchid = id
GROUP BY game.id
ORDER BY mdate,matchid,team1,team2
```

I get the result "Too few rows". I don't understand what part I got wrong.

Comment: On separate columns you have to have aggregate functions or add them on GROUP BY.I think that message is a custom one for sqlzoo.

Comment: You're missing the 0-0 score, so you need to widen your join out to include all `game` rows, including those not featured in the `goal` table.

Comment: You need to get the score of each team separately by using join

Answer (score 29, accepted):

An `INNER JOIN` only returns games where there have been goals, i.e. matches between the `goal` and `game` table.

What you need is a `LEFT JOIN`. You need all the rows from your first table, `game` but they don't need to match all the rows in `goal`, as per the 0-0 comment I made on your question:

```
SELECT game.mdate, game.team1, 
SUM(CASE WHEN goal.teamid = game.team1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS score1,
game.team2,
SUM(CASE WHEN goal.teamid = game.team2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS score2

FROM game LEFT JOIN goal ON matchid = id
GROUP BY game.id,game.mdate, game.team1, game.team2 
ORDER BY mdate,matchid,team1,team2
```

This returns the 0-0 result between Portugal and Spain on 27th June, which your initial answer missed out.

Answer (score 3):

As there are columns with the same names in both tables, no need to specify where the current column is coming from.

```
SELECT mdate, team1, 

SUM(CASE WHEN teamid = team1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS score1,

team2,

SUM(CASE WHEN teamid = team2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS score2

FROM game LEFT JOIN goal ON matchid = id

GROUP BY mdate, team1, team2

ORDER BY mdate,matchid,team1,team2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT game.mdate, game.team1, 
SUM(CASE WHEN goal.teamid = game.team1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) score1,
game.team2,
SUM(CASE WHEN goal.teamid = game.team2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) score2
FROM game LEFT JOIN goal ON matchid = id
GROUP BY mdate, team1, team2
```

Answer (score 1):

I Did it using a subquery.

The only trick here is to understand that we need to use Left Join AND not inner join as there are games which have 0 goals scored which do not capture in our query if we use the inner join(the 0-0 case)

Hope below query helps!

```
select t1.mdate,t1.team1,sum(t1.score1),t1.team2,sum(t1.score2) from(
SELECT mdate,
  team1,
  CASE WHEN teamid=team1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END score1,
  team2,
  CASE WHEN teamid=team2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END score2
  FROM game JOIN goal ON matchid = id)t1
group by t1.mdate,t1.team1,t1.team2
order by mdate,team1,team2
```

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL the answer by @mjsqu works, but `for SQL Server` and some other dialects you need to `specify all the columns` in the `GROUP BY`. So if you're familiair with MySQL, remember that in some dialects you have to be more specific in the GROUP BY (unfortunately...). Beneath a script that works for SQL Server:

```
SELECT    game.mdate 
,         game.team1
,         SUM(CASE WHEN goal.teamid=game.team1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) score1 
,         game.team2
,         SUM(CASE WHEN goal.teamid=game.team2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) score2
FROM game LEFT JOIN goal 
  ON game.id=goal.matchid
GROUP BY  game.mdate, goal.matchid, game.team1, game.team2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT game.mdate,
       game.team1, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN goal.teamid = game.team1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS score1,
       game.team2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN goal.teamid = game.team2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS score2
FROM game LEFT JOIN goal ON game.id = goal.matchid
GROUP BY game.id, game.mdate, game.team1, game.team2 
ORDER BY game.mdate, game.id, game.team1, game.team2;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You should add explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are working in SQLZOO

```sql
SELECT mdate, team1,
       sum(CASE
               WHEN teamid=team1 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
           END) score1,
       team2,
       sum(CASE
               WHEN teamid=team2 THEN '1'
               ELSE'0'
           END) score2
FROM game
JOIN goal ON matchid = id
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY mdate, matchid, team1, team2
```

Answer (score -1):

`

```
SELECT ga.mdate, ga.team1,
SUM(CASE WHEN go.teamid=ga.team1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) score1,
ga.team2,
SUM(CASE WHEN go.teamid=ga.team2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) score2
FROM game ga LEFT JOIN goal go ON go.matchid = ga.id
GROUP BY ga.mdate, go.matchid, ga.team1, ga.team2
```

`

Comment: Please add an explanation for your answer, as it is this isn't going to help someone solve or understand the problem.