# Why are these JOIN statements affecting my order clause in different ways?

Tags: mysql, join, sql-order-by

I'm familiarizing myself with SQL on sqlzoo, and the final question (#13) was giving issues until I successfully guessed the solution. I initially suspected I had written my ORDER BY clause wrong or that improper data type was to blame, but then [I looked up a solution provided by mjsqu here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081938/whats-wrong-with-my-query-with-case-statement). I only changed the JOIN statement and removed the ORDER BY clause to match their code. Frankly, I still don't understand why the ORDER BY statement was failing to sort the date in the first place.

See here for data and problem set: https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/The_JOIN_operation

```
SELECT mdate,
  team1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN teamid=team1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) score1,
  team2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN teamid=team2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) score2
FROM game JOIN goal ON matchid = id
GROUP BY mdate, matchid, team1, team2
ORDER BY mdate, matchid, team1, team2
```

Solution code:

```
SELECT mdate, 
   team1,
   SUM(CASE WHEN teamid = team1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) score1,
   team2,
   SUM(CASE WHEN teamid = team2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) score2
FROM game LEFT JOIN goal ON matchid = id 
GROUP BY mdate, matchid, team1, team2
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two queries is for games where there are no goals. `INNER JOIN` won't return any rows for those games. `LEFT JOIN` will return a row for those games, but all the columns from the `goals` table will be `NULL`.

Since you're grouping and ordering by `goal.matchid`, this will group all those games with no goals together when the other grouping columns are the same. You should use `game.id` instead of `goal.matchid` in both `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`.

```
SELECT mdate, 
   team1,
   SUM(CASE WHEN teamid = team1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) score1,
   team2,
   SUM(CASE WHEN teamid = team2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) score2
FROM game LEFT JOIN goal ON matchid = id 
GROUP BY mdate, id, team1, team2
ORDER BY mdate, id, team1, team2
```